# Why is light produced when an underwater bubble is collapsed with a sound wave?

Tags: visible-light, acoustics, bubbles

Why is light produced when an underwater bubble is collapsed with a sound wave?

I have come across this fact on a page ([similar to this](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=tiny-bubbles-explain-puzz)) but can't understand "Why". I'm just curious about this interesting fact. And, I want to know what's the currently accepted model for this phenomenon and how good it holds. Any kind of help regarding this topic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: here is a link you could have found by google. http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=tiny-bubbles-explain-puzz . This link gives some models/reasons.

Comment: the article in wikipedia is quite complete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence .

Comment: Regarding the second question: no, the argument about the mechanism of sonoluminescence is not settled and there are several competing theories.

Answer (score 4):

There is a detailed review of this phenomenon [here](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v74/i2/p425_1)

The phenomenon is known as sonoluminescence.  One of the leading theories is that it is caused by "adiabatic heating of the bubble at collapse, leading to partial ionization of the gas inside the bubble and to thermal emission such as bremsstrahlung."