# Is the energy of sonoluminescence derived solely from ultrasound?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, acoustics, bubbles

[Sonoluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence) occurs when a small gas bubble is oscillated in a liquid solution with ultrasonic frequencies. The bubble's collapse and cavitation results in light emission and thermal energies that may be as high as 6000 K to 20,000 K.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_of_sonoluminescence

Is the energy emission of sonoluminescence the result of the external acoustical waves or is it derived from non-external energy sources like virtual particle annihilation?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66044/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The original energy which causes sonoluminescence comes from the sound field. The result of sonoluminescence is ultimately a product of vibration due to the sound field being applied.

https://acoustics-research.physics.ucla.edu/sonoluminescence/
https://www.physics.ncsu.edu/weninger/SLreview.pdf

Comment: I have read that some believe the light is related to the creation of plasma: https://physics.aps.org/articles/v7/72 I am just trying to understand how an oscillating  cavitation creates plasma

Comment: @RichardStanzak The compression due to the sound waves result in a high temperature. This temperature is actually high enough to ionize the gas. And those ions can now emit light. (So, the plasma is simply created due to head by compression).